# Help me in optimising the query which takes almost 50 seconds

Tags: query-performance, optimization, execution-plan, performance-tuning, mysql-8.0

Please help me optimise the following query running on MySQL 8.0.28 Community Edition.

```
explain select id, 
        created_at, 
        data, 
        deleted_at, 
        entity_id, 
        entity_type, 
        updated_at, 
        version 
from items 
where JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.invoiceNumber'))='MKNS22-23-000165' 
and JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.poBarCode'))='ABCD-AJSJ130258-1' 
and (entity_type in ('GOT_TICK')) 
and (deleted_at is null or deleted_at >'2023-02-22 09:20:08.063');


+----+-------------+--------+------------+------+-----------------+-----------------+---------+-------+---------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table  | partitions | type | possible_keys   | key             | key_len | ref   | rows    | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+------+-----------------+-----------------+---------+-------+---------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | items  | NULL       | ref  | entity_type_idx | entity_type_idx | 92      | const | 5381058 |    40.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+------+-----------------+-----------------+---------+-------+---------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)


show indexes from items;
+-------+------------+-----------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name        | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Visible | Expression |
+-------+------------+-----------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| items |          0 | PRIMARY         |            1 | id          | A         |    10716855 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| items |          1 | entity_type_idx |            1 | entity_type | A         |         551 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| items |          1 | entity_id_idx   |            1 | entity_id   | A         |      204232 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
+-------+------------+-----------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)


 CREATE TABLE `items` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `entity_type` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `entity_id` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `data` json NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `version` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `entity_type_idx` (`entity_type`),
  KEY `entity_id_idx` (`entity_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=20555956 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 ;
```

I tried creating a composite index on `deleted_at` and `entity_type` and a separate index on `deleted_at`, but it did not help.

```
show indexes from items;
+-------+------------+---------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name                        | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Visible | Expression |
+-------+------------+---------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| items |          0 | PRIMARY                         |            1 | id          | A         |    13987955 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| items |          1 | entity_type_idx                 |            1 | entity_type | A         |         534 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| items |          1 | entity_id_idx                   |            1 | entity_id   | A         |      269627 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| items |          1 | deleted_at_idx                  |            1 | deleted_at  | A         |        9069 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| items |          1 | entity_type_deleted_at_comp_idx |            1 | entity_type | A         |         480 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| items |          1 | entity_type_deleted_at_comp_idx |            2 | deleted_at  | A         |       24518 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
+-------+------------+---------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
```

If I understand it correctly, even if I create an index on `data`, it would not use that index. If I move the functions used in the `where` clause on the `data` column to the right of the equation, would that change anything?

The table size is 16 GB.

It's 16 core machine with CentOS 7 with 44GB RAM for MySQL 8.0.28 Community Edition.

Comment: [Indexing a Generated Column to Provide a JSON Column Index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-secondary-indexes.html#json-column-indirect-index). Personally I never use json columns especially if I have to make a lot of data manipulation .

Comment: thanks for response @ErgestBasha - so if I create the generated columns and index them, will it be helpful?

Comment: yes. In the explain plan you could easily see that no index is used.

Answer (score 0):

To utilize indexes on `deleted_at` and `entity_type`, you need to rewrite your query to a `union all` query.

```
    select /*QB_2*/ items.id, items.created_at, items.data, items.deleted_at,
items.entity_id, items.entity_type, items.updated_at, items.version
from items
where JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(items.data, '$.invoiceNumber')) = 'MKNS22-23-000165'
  and JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(items.data, '$.poBarCode')) = 'ABCD-AJSJ130258-1'
  and items.entity_type in ('GOT_TICK')
  and items.deleted_at > '2023-02-22 09:20:08.063' 
union all
select /*QB_1*/ items.id, items.created_at, items.data, items.deleted_at,
items.entity_id, items.entity_type, items.updated_at, items.version
from items
where JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(items.data, '$.invoiceNumber')) = 'MKNS22-23-000165'
  and JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(items.data, '$.poBarCode')) = 'ABCD-AJSJ130258-1'
  and items.entity_type in ('GOT_TICK') and items.deleted_at is null
```

[Here is the tuning details](https://app.pawsql.com/statement/1640957662357098497) provide by my query tuning tool(PawSQL).